# how to have a div which reloads seperate to page

Tags: html, ajax, database, forum

I was wondering if I can have a div which can load instead of the whole page. As an example to explain but is not possible but like a seperate window were you can control. But instead I have a text-box I don't want to use Ajax since I've tried many ways but nothing works. I don't want a page reload. If you need any questions answers please comment bellow.

Comment: Please post the ways you have tried then it will be easier for people to help you. Some examples of what you mean from other websites will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided much detail, I will let myself hold a few assumptions about your code.

Suppose you have a `<div>`, say `<div id="box_to_load">`, and another element, say `<span id="click_to_load">` which when get clicked triggers the loading.

In such case, you can I would go for a CSS play. Initially set your `<div>` to have `display:none` or no visibility, depends on what fits best. Then, on click, make the div visible. So `<div id="box_to_load">` becomes `<div id="box_to_load" style="visibilty:hidden;">` and `<span id="click_to_load">` becomes `<span id="click_to_load" onclick="document.getElementById('box_to_load').visibility = 'visible'>`

I hope I got you right.

Comment: thanks. I'm not good at explaining what i want. your answer is good. but i have a forum, but when i click the submit it reloads the whole page. i made it so it comes back to that page but i don't want any reloading of the page.

Comment: @Jack You did not mention any submission before. Please post some code about that submission so it would be easier to see how does the reload occur.